# Pydev "Run/Debug configurations" does not find main module from external folder

Tags: eclipse, pydev

I have added an external source folder to my project via "Project->Properties->External Libraries->Add source folder". Added folder and underlying source files appear under "External libs" on the "Pydev Package Explorer" perspective.

When I try to set up "Run (or debug) configurations->Main->Main module" using the "Browse ..." button, I'm given an empty window. I understand that is happening because the main project folder has no source files to this point. So, my question is: how can I then have the main module being run/debugged coming from external python sources? I consider linking the external source folder from the main project folder not to be an option.

I'm using Eclipse Kepler Service Release 2, Build id: 20140212-2123
and PyDev for Eclipse 2.8.2.2013090511

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

In this case you can do a run configuration which points to the external file...

In practice, open the external file you want to run and press 'F9'. It'll then ask for the project to be used to get the PYTHONPATH.

A note thought: I know this works in the latest PyDev (3.6.0), but you're saying you have a much older version of PyDev, so, you may have to update to get it working... (note that the latest PyDev requires java 7, so, follow the instructions at http://pydev.org/download.html to get it to work -- or get http://brainwy.github.io/liclipse/ for an eclipse standalone with the latest PyDev builtin).

Comment: Sorry for taking too long to get back to you and thanks for the answer. It turns out that the best way to deal with this problem in my setup was to use External Tools->External Tools Configurations and write shell scripts that would call the external python commands directly.